# php get list of files as array, output 1 random file name with extension.

Tags: php

So what i am trying to do is get a list of text files from a directory.

take that list and randomly choose 1 file.

then take that file and print out the contents. now i did this a few years back.  but can't find my old script. i tried what i have below just to print out a file name.. but event that is not working?

```
$path  = '/seg1';
$files = scandir($path);

$seg = array ( $files );

$rand_keys = array_rand($seg, 1);

print $rand_keys;
```

Would love some new eyes on this as well as any input.

Comment: `scandir()` also returns `.`, `..` and directories in general. You will want to use `glob()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*** Search All files in Dir. with .txt extension ***/ 

foreach (glob('./seg1/*.txt') as $filename)
  {
  $myFiles[] = $filename;
/*** Array of file names **/
}

/*** Total count of files ***/

$max=sizeof($myFiles);

/*** Select a Random index for Array with Max limit  ***/

$fileNo=rand(0, $max);

/*** Path of the Random file to Access ***/ 

$file=$myFiles[$fileNo];

/*** Get the content from Text file ****/

$data = file_get_contents($file, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

As your variable naming suggests, you randomly select one *key* out of the array; try getting the value by

```
$filename = $seg[$rand_keys];
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you use **glob** so you only get files you want, this excludes system directories like `.` and `..`

```
foreach (glob("seg1/*.txt") as $filename) {
  $seg[] = $filename;
}
```

Or an even simpler solution:

```
$rand_keys = array_rand(glob("seg1/*.txt"), 1);
```

Comment: ok so how would i turn the output for the files for the glob into an array?

Comment: A glob returns an array already, so you can just use `array_rand` directly on the glob; see my updated answer above - it does what you want in one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
$path  = '/seg1';
$files = scandir($path));
if($files)
    echo file_get_contents($files[mt_rand(2,count($files))]);
```